# Is it possible to add a custom emoji with different skin tone in Slack?

Tags: slack, emoji, emoji-tones

Let's say I have a custom GIF emoji `:alert:` with multiple colored versions.

Is it possible to assign those a different skin tone modifiers to avoid creating multiple emojis with different names, e.g. `:alert::skin-tone-2:` instead of `:alert_blue:`, `:alert_green:` etc?

I've tried naming it `:alert::skin-tone-2:`, but got an error **Names must be lowercase, and can’t contain spaces, periods, or most punctuation.** Maybe there's another option?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you could get a straight solution for it. You could try a hack. For that, you'll need to have an image of that skin tone. Then upload it and if you need a way to upload it in bulk check out this video
https://youtu.be/K_u2UBtARmI

These would be the following steps to upload emojis in bulk on slack:

- Go here: https://slackmojis.com/
- Click the emojis that you like (instant download)
- Get this Chrome extenstion: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/neutral-face-emoji-tools/anchoacphlfbdomdlomnbbfhcmcdmjej
- Go to https://<your_team>.slack.com/customize/emoji.
- Drag'n'drop all emojis on the Bulk Emoji Uploader drop area

Comment: The problem is that I cannot set skin tones when uploading.